# Getting error while performing web3 transaction from chrome extention

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, blockchain, web3js

I am able to retrieve data from block-chain with chrome extension but error is coming when updating some block from chrome extension.

using below code for performing transaction.

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method === "getHTML") {
  console.log("Hello From react 2");
  console.log(request.data);
  const ads = await userAbi.methods.setSpecificUserClickStatistics(request.data).send({from: "some address"});
  console.log(ads);
}
});
```

Success output when run `console.log(web3.currentProvider)` connected with Web3.

```
   HttpProvider {host: "https://rinkeby.infura.io/<specific token>", timeout: 0, connected: false, headers: undefined}
connected:true
headers:undefined
host:"https://rinkeby.infura.io/<specific token>"
timeout:0
event.js:24170 Hello From react 2
```

Error which I am getting :-

```
event.js:60196 POST https://rinkeby.infura.io/(specific token) 405 ()
HttpProvider.send @ event.js:60196
RequestManager.send @ event.js:50121
sendRequest @ event.js:8961
(anonymous) @ event.js:8978
sendTxCallback @ event.js:8885
(anonymous) @ event.js:50136
request.onreadystatechange @ event.js:60186
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
HttpProvider.send @ event.js:60196
RequestManager.send @ event.js:50121
sendRequest @ event.js:8961
send @ event.js:8982
send @ event.js:8973
_executeMethod @ event.js:56098
(anonymous) @ event.js:24172
EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:403
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:387
EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:409
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
messageListener @ extensions::messaging:240
EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:403
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:387
EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:409
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:392
event.js:49362 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (event.js:49362)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (event.js:60182)
InvalidResponse @ event.js:49362
request.onreadystatechange @ event.js:60182
async function (async)
(anonymous) @ event.js:24168
EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:403
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:387
EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:409
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
messageListener @ extensions::messaging:240
EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:403
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:387
EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:409
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:138
dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:392
```

Any help will be a great help.

Comment: Chrome extensions API does not support Promise so you can't pass `async function` where a normal function is expected by the API. You can define a separate async function and invoke it from the API callback.

Answer (score 0):

can you try these :

1. Try to check if testrpc is running or is it stopped.
2. Also, can you try to use http instead of https

One of these might do the trick from my exp. The first of course is for running the envt and in case of the second, it sometimes doesnt allow you to connect to the node.

Hope this helps. Good luck.